# Python get deep json value

Tags: python, json

```
  {
  "export": {
    "version": "3.4",
    "date": "2018-08-09T13:19:46Z",
    "groups": [
      {
        "name": "Templates"
      }
    ],
    "templates": [
      {
        "template": "Template OS",
        "name": "Template OS",
        "description": "",
        "groups": [
          {
            "name": "Datawhatiwant"
          }
        ],
```

This is the relevant part of the JSON code and i want the value ***datawhatiwant***.
But if I use `print json_data["export"]` there is this error: 
`TypeError: string indices must be integers`
So how can I get *datawhatiwant*?

Comment: where did you get your `json_data` from?

Comment: also your JSON-object example is not complete

Comment: It seems like you have a string. You need to use `json.loads` to convert the string to a python object

Comment: @Bakuriu I already use json.loads

Comment: @t0mThen you are probably doing that incorrectly. If youn provided us with the actual code you are using we could probably told you were the problem is in a matter of 2 minutes, but we can only guess with the little information you provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to decode the json first

```
import json

print(json.loads(json_data)["export"])
```

Should work better, I think.

Comment: I already decode json:
`req = requests.get(url, data=json.dumps(reg), headers=headers)
json_data = json.loads(req.text)
print json_data["export]`

Comment: Well, what do you get if you just print json_data? I'm guessing it's going to be a string...

Comment: This is the relevant part from the json output:
`{u'jsonrpc': u'2.0', u'result': u'{"export":{"version":"3.4","date":"2018-08-10T06:15:39Z","groups":[{"name":"Templates"}],"templates":[{"template":"Template FS","name":"Template FS","description":"","groups":[{"name":"datawhatiwant"}]`

Comment: Look at the value of the result key. It's a string, just as your error claims. That's what you need to give to json.loads()

Comment: Like this? `print json.loads(json_data["result"][2])`

Comment: It's hard to say, you're not being very clear about what data is where. Is the object you posted in your comment the result of print(json_data)?

Comment: Yes it is and I want the data from the second *groups* array.

Comment: In that case, try parsed_obj = (json.loads(json_data['result'])) That should give you a python object and you can get whatever key or array index you want out of it from there